# JSF: Resource bundle key (name) as EL expression?

Tags: jsf, el

How to make work something like that:

```
<c:forEach items="#{bean.data}" var="key" >
   <h:outputText value="#{m[#{key}]}" />
</c:forEach>
```

I need to get value from messages.properties, but dynamically using #{} expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
<h:outputText value="#{m[key]}" />
```