# JSF localization of dynamic expressions

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a bean with a status field which can take one of three predefined values: ACTIVE, BLOCKED, DELETED. For each of those, I defined a label in a properties file:

```
entity.status.ACTIVE=Active
entity.status.BLOCKED=Blocked
entity.status.DELETED=Deleted
```

Is there any way of displaying the entity's status' label? More exactly, is there a way of combining the static 'entity.status.' string with the dynamic status value to get a key for a resource bundle? I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683545/jsf-resource-bundle-key-name-as-el-expression), but it doesn't answer my needs completely

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `concat` function like this:

```
#{myResourceBundle['entity.statut.'.concat(myBean.status)]}
```